# Tomato plant, fungal, can anyone help me save them?

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes, recovery

I am new to the site as well as growing tomatoes, so any help would really be appreciated!

I have attached photos of my tomato plants.
White spots appeared on the leaves and I applied diluted neem oil thinking it was fungus. Since then, the leaves have been browning and slowly dying. The white fungus has spread to the stems.

I have put so much effort into growing my tomato plants and really would love to see them produce fruit!

Is there any way salvage and revive these plants?

[image]
[image]